# How to perform a search query using Services_Twitter?

Tags: php, api, twitter, service, pear

I am trying to perform a Twitter search using the PEAR package Services_Twitter.
Unfortunately this only returns an array of status ids, for example *(var_dump)*:

```
object(stdClass)#88 (2) {
  ["statuses"]=>
  array(11) {
    [0]=>
    int(49497593539)
    [1]=>
    int(49497593851)
    [2]=>
    int(49497598001)
    [3]=>
    int(49497599055)
    [4]=>
    int(49497599597)
    [5]=>
    int(49497600733)
    [6]=>
    int(49497602607)
    [7]=>
    int(49497607031)
    [8]=>
    int(49497607453)
    [9]=>
    int(49497609577)
    [10]=>
    int(49497610605)
  }
  ["created_in"]=>
  float(0.008847)
}
```

The script I'm using is similar to this test script I wrote:

```
<?php
//$oAuth = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer( /** Supply oAuth details here **/ );
$Twitter = new Services_Twitter();
//$Twitter->setOAuth($oAuth);
try {
    $Response = $Twitter->search(array(
      "q"   => "#FF -RT OR #FollowFriday -RT",
      "rpp" => 10,
      "since_id"  => 23982086000,
      "result_type" => "recent"
    ));
    var_dump($Response);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    fwrite(STDERR, $e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

Since I want to scan the tweets for certain words and want to know when it was posted and by whom, I would need to request all these statuses one by one.
But according to the [example response in the Twitter API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search#example-requests) they already return all the necessary information about the tweets (which is kinda obvious).

So, the question is: How can I access this information using Services_Twitter?

Kind Regards,

Arno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I said `->search()` is wrapped through `Services_Twitter::__call()`.

But here's the mis-understanding!

Two searches:

- http://api.twitter.com/1/search.json?q=@noradio
- http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@noradio

This is confusing as `search.twitter.com` returns the results as you'd expect them and the other API method just the status IDs.

For some reason only when you search for trends `search.twitter.com` is used. Otherwise it's the API methods. If you want to help, please open a ticket on PEAR and I can try to implement this for you.

A quickfix for you is this script:

```
<?php
$uri  = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?';
$uri .= http_build_query(
    array(
        "q"           => "#FF -RT OR #FollowFriday -RT",
        "rpp"         => 10,
        "since_id"    => 23982086000,
        "result_type" => "recent"
));

$response = file_get_contents($uri);
if ($response === false) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Could not fetch search result.");
    exit(1);
}

$data = json_decode($response);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I will adjust my ticket on the PEAR site as soon as possible. I wanted to use oAuth, to perform more searches/hour (since oauth calls have a higher rate-limit). Correct me if I'm wrong, it might be different for the Search API ofcourse.

Comment: No, no - you're probably correct. I wonder if the oauth'd API supports what you want though. From what I see, by looking at the straight request, the API only returns those user IDs. So in turn, you'd need to look up the full message - one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom [`Services_Twitter`](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Twitter/docs/0.6.3/Services_Twitter/Services_Twitter.html), I just did a search through the class via Pear Documentation and was unable to find the `search` function.  However, it seems like most of the returns for that class is a [simple_xml](http://www.php.net/simple_xml) object. Given that I would look through the documentation there and see how you can pull that data out. It would also help looking at how Twitter returns the response in XML format.

Comment: Btw, the default response is JSON.

Comment: From the Twitter API, but the Services_Twitter returns simple_xml element.  From the Doc for __call()  `Return: of SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: `Services_Twitter::$options` says JSON it is. The docs need some updates! :)

Comment: Gotcha :P Well cannot help bad documentation.